# Swift: Dismissing sheet doesn’t work after hitting Button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

After clicking the „Hinzufügen" button (its German), closing the "AddView" with the „Fertig" button no longer works. However, if „Hinzufügen" was not clicked beforehand, the „Fertig" button works. Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

class DestinationModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var names: String = ""
    @Published var shops: String = ""
    @Published var cuts: String = ""
    @Published var prices: String = ""
    
    
    @Published var showingAddView: Bool = false
    
    
}




struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var destinationModel: DestinationModel = DestinationModel()
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query var destinations: [Destination]
    
    
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 247/255)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Produkt")
                            Text("Shop")
                            Text("Sparvorteil")
                            Text("Preis")
                        }
                        
                        List {
                            if destinations.isEmpty {
                                ContentUnavailableView(label: {
                                    Label("Keine Produkte eingetragen", systemImage: "cart.badge.plus")
                                }, description: {
                                    Text("Geplante Einkäufe werden hier angezeigt.")
                                }, actions: {
                                    Button("Hinzufügen") {
                                        destinationModel.showingAddView = true
                                    }
                                    .sheet(isPresented: $destinationModel.showingAddView, content: {
                                        AddView(destinationModel: destinationModel)
                                    })
                                })
                                
                            } else {
                                ForEach(destinations) { destination in
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(destination.name)
                                        Text(destination.shop)
                                        Text(destination.cut)
                                        Text(destination.price)
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                .onDelete { IndexSet in
                                    for index in IndexSet {
                                        context.delete(destinations[index])
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Geplante Einkäufe")
                        
                         
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            
            }
            
        
        }
                
    }
    

struct AddView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var destinationModel: DestinationModel
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Fertig") {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .font(.title3)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            TextField("Name", text: $destinationModel.names)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(width: 280, height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                .font(.title2)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)))
            TextField("Shop", text: $destinationModel.shops)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(width: 280, height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                .font(.title2)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)))
            TextField("Preis", text: $destinationModel.prices)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(width: 280, height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                .font(.title2)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)))
            TextField("Vergünstigung", text: $destinationModel.cuts)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .frame(width: 280, height: 40, alignment: .trailing)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                .font(.title2)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 10)))
            Spacer()
        }
        
        Button("Hinzufügen") {
            let kauf = Destination(name: destinationModel.names, shop: destinationModel.shops, cut: destinationModel.cuts, price: destinationModel.prices)
            context.insert(kauf)
            
            
            
            destinationModel.cuts = ""
            destinationModel.shops = ""
            destinationModel.prices = ""
            destinationModel.names = ""
            
        }
        
        
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I tried several things with "presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()“ but it never worked. Has someone else a solution? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Did you try using dismiss instead of presentationMode and having only one included in the code? I don't understand why `DestinationModel` even exists, the bool property can be a State property in the ContentView and the others can be State properties in the AddView. Or if you for some other reason need it why not just make it local in the AddView.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `NavigationStack`, you must be targeting iOS 16 or later. In which case, there is a better way to dismiss a view.

Since iOS 15, you can use the environment value `dismiss` to dismiss a view - the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss) even includes an example to show how this can be used for a sheet. You have already included this environment value in `AddView`, but you don't appear to be using it.

So I would suggest the following changes:

1. In `ContentView`, move the `.sheet` modifier to the parent `ZStack`:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    ZStack {
        // content as before, except for the .sheet modifier on the Button
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $destinationModel.showingAddView) { // <- now here instead
        AddView(destinationModel: destinationModel)
    }
}
```

2. In `AddView`, use `dismiss()` as the button action:

```swift
@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
// @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode // not needed
```

```swift
Button("Fertig") {
    // presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    dismiss()
}
```

Alternatively, you could just reset the boolean binding that controls the visibility of the sheet:

```swift
Button("Fertig") {
    // presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    // dismiss()
    destinationModel.showingAddView = false // works too
}
```

3. Add a parent container to `AddView`

The `body` of `AddView` contains 2 `VStack` and a `Button` at top level. You might want to surround these with a `VStack`, to define the layout for the view:

```swift
// AddView

var body: some View {
    VStack { // <- ADDED

        VStack {
            // content as before
        }

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            // content as before
        }

        Button("Hinzufügen") {
            // content as before
        }
    }
}
```